# Appendix pagenumbering A-1, A-2, only works for the first section? (Does not work for B-1, B-2, ...)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, page-numbering, appendices, appendix

I have tried to use this to get the desiered pagenumbering: `A-1`, `A-2`, ... , `B-1`, `B-2`, ...

```
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

This only works for the first section.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}   

\begin{document}
\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage % Need an empty page after my bibliogrophy
\appendix
\appendixpage

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Test A}
\label{A}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\section{Test B}
\label{B}
\lipsum[3]

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `\begin{appendince}` ... `\end{appedince}` beside `\appendinx` is superfluous. Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]

\clearpage
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}

\section{Test A}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\label{A}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\section{Test B}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\label{B}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```